# Replace Date Format YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS Into Formatted Date

Tags: php, date, time, date-formatting

I have a folder full of files formatted like this...

```
2017-06-30-18-21-52 foo.txt
2017-07-01-19-06-21 bar bar.txt
```

With the desired echoed output of:

```
"Foo" -- June 30th, 2017
"Bar Bar" -- July 7th, 2017
```

The "th" and "rd" bits aren't strictly necessary, but it never hurts to ask as it's nice looking.

Comment: $parts = explode(' ', $note, 2);
$dateString = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($parts[0]));
echo '-- ' + $dateString;    # this returns 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim the extension away. This assumes that its always `.txt` and nothing else. Then you get the date by exploding on spaces, get the first value - which is the date - unset it, so that when you glue it back together with `implode()`, it's not included.

Because `2017-06-30-18-21-52` is not a valid format to pass to a DateTime constructor, we use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

```
$array = array();
$array[] = "2017-06-30-18-21-52 foo.txt";
$array[] = "2017-07-01-19-06-21 bar bar.txt";

foreach ($array as $v) {
    $v = rtrim($v, ".txt");
    $boom = explode(" ", $v);   // Separate the date 
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d-H-i-s", $boom[0]);
    unset($boom[0]);             // Unset the date
    $text = implode(" ", $boom);

    echo $text." -- ".$date->format("F jS, Y")."\n";
}
```

Output:

> foo -- June 30th, 2017
>   bar bar -- July 1st, 2017

If you wish to have the `foo` and  `bar bar` capitalized, you can use a function such as `ucwords()`.

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/X6L6Y)

- http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat
- http://php.net/function.rtrim
- http://php.net/function.ucwords.

Comment: Hey.  that worked!  I had originally neglected to do the full "Y-m-d-H-i-s" formatted string since most of the examples online just do y,m,d.  I guess i thought the function used pixie dust to guess that the last 3 parts weren't relevant for my case.  Also, the date->format example was very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: If this is a solution that works for you, please mark an answer as accepted - that way, future readers will know that you have found a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use **Regex** to extract data from those format.

```
<?php
$files = [
    "2017-06-30-18-21-52 foo.txt",
    "2017-07-01-19-06-21 bar bar.txt"
];

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo format($file), PHP_EOL;
}

function format($file) {
    $result = "";
    $match  = [];
    $assert = preg_match("/^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-z ]*)/is", $file, $match);
    if ($assert== true) {
       $date   = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $match[1]);
       $result = ucwords($match[3]) . " -- " . $date->format("F jS, Y");
    } else {
       $result = $file;
    }

    return $result;
}
```